# Why do i keep getting a NullPointerException while using AppCompatActivity to create a custom Action Bar in Android?

Tags: java, android, appcompatactivity

I am relatively new to Android and have been going at this for about two days now and cannot find any solution. It seems that whenever I try to access my activity's action bar the app cannot find a compatible action bar. I suspect this is because of something that I am missing because of the relatively new AppCompatActivity update making the available theme incompatible with the Action Bar.

Essentially, all I want to do is add the setDisplayHomeUpEnabled to my Action Bar.

Here is my Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.snackbar, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addListenerOnButton();
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

My Action Bar:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/padlock"
      android:title="@string/app_name"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
      android:icon="@drawable/padlock"
      android:title="@string/action_compose"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

My Manifest:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.Passwords"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/padlock"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="Activity2"
                android:parentActivityName="com.example.Passwords.MyActivity"
                android:label="@string/second">

        </activity>


    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any help resolving this problem is appreciated.

Comment: If you're using the AppCompatActivity, use a Toolbar instead of an ActionBar.

Comment: Which style are in using. Go to style.xml and see and share with us

Comment: your actionbar is null, quick guesses, in your Theme parent you have NoTitleBar or you did not call `SetSupportActionBar(toolbar)` so getting the actionbar is `null` follow @BidhanA suggestion